# Is it sufficient to prove that anything that is not a cluster point is automatically an isolated point?

Tags: real-analysis

I am looking at the set $B = \{\frac{1}{n}|n \in \mathbb{N} \}$. I know there is only one cluster point that is 0 but I do not know if it is sufficient to use this proof:

Choose $\epsilon > 0$. Then there exists $x \in B$\{$0$} st $0 < |x-0| < \epsilon$.

The reason why I am confused is that I proved one point but I didn't prove *the* point. So technically it isn't a full proof since I only proved a single instance and not for all instances. Then, I know by intuition that every single other point in this set are isolated points since at each point, there is no small $\epsilon > 0$ that the interval can get it to any other point in the set. But how can I prove this?

Comment: What is $B\{0\}$?

Comment: Oh whoops. Meant to put B \{0}

Comment: But 0 is not in $B$...

Comment: Yes that is the point.. 0 doesn't have to be in B to be a cluster point

Comment: Yes, and $0$ *isn't* in $B$ so $B\setminus \{0\} = B$.  *If* you show that $0$ is a cluster point of $B$ then you've shown that $0\in B$ and then you can write $\bar{B}\setminus \{0\}$

Answer (score 0):

If $a\in\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$, then, since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n=0$, there is some $\varepsilon>0$ such that $(a-\varepsilon,a+\varepsilon)$ only has finitely many numbers of the form $\frac1n$ ($n\in\Bbb N$). Let $F$ be that set. Then $F\setminus\{a\}$ is still a finite set. Let$$m=\min\left\{\left|a-\frac1n\right|\,\middle|\,\frac1n\in F\setminus\{a\}\right\}$$(take $m=\varepsilon$ if $F\setminus\{a\}$ is empty). Then$$\left(a-\min\{\varepsilon,m\},a+\min\{\varepsilon,m\}\right)\cap\left\{\frac1n\,\middle|\,n\in\Bbb N\right\}=\begin{cases}a&\text{ if $a=\frac1n$ for some $n\in\Bbb N$}\\\emptyset&\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$and therefore $a$ is not a cluster point of $\left\{\frac1n\,\middle|\,n\in\Bbb N\right\}$.